# How to specify dimension of Google Charts in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-visualization

I would like to know how to specify the dimension of Google charts in asp.net.
I am using http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/create-google-multi-series-column-chart-from-database-in-Asp-Net-1065.aspx tutorial.

I have a `<div>` that has set the width as 30%, I need to add the Google Chart to this . In this this width is specified as:-

```
str.Append("chart.draw(data, {width: 650, height: 300, title: 'Company Performance'");
```

How do I properly fill this Google chart in my `<div>` of width 35% ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one or both dimensions set on the container div, you don't need to specify those dimensions in the chart options; the chart will default to 100% of the container's width or height when not specified.  Since you have your width set in the container, remove the width option like this:

```
str.Append("chart.draw(data, {height: 300, title: 'Company Performance'");
```